# How do I set Axis2 to use (complex) data types with custom schema?

Tags: java, wsdl, apache-axis

I'm currently working on some set of Web services that take POJOs/beans as parameters that will be deployed through Axis2. The problem is that the built-in code for Axis2 that generates the WSDL represent the POJOs in a way different from what I need.

For example, I have the following classes:

```
public class Employee {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    //mutators, accessors
}

public class Department {
    private String name;
    private List<Employee> employees;
    //mutators, accessors
}
```

I would like the XML to look like (minus all the namespace data):

```
<department>
  <name>marketing<name>
  <employees>
    <employee>
      <firstName>Juan</firstName>
      <lastName>dela Cruz</lastName>
    <employee>
    <employee>
      <firstName>Pedro</firstName>
      <lastName>Mahusay</lastName>
    <employee>
  </employees>
<department>
```

However, Axis2 would represent the above XML to be:

```
<department>
  <name>marketing<name>
  <employees>
    <firstName>Juan</firstName>
    <lastName>dela Cruz</lastName>
  </employees>
  <employees>
    <firstName>Pedro</firstName>
    <lastName>Mahusay</lastName>
  <employees>
<department>
```

I've looked into MessageBuilders and MessageFormatters but I'm still not sure how to process the XML into an OMElement (in the case of Builder) to make it work. I don't know how Axis2 transforms these OMElements into Beans that the Web service code can use. Is there a (maybe simpler or more logical/efficient?) way to make it work like the first one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an object of **Employees** that contains a list of **Employee** object.

It would be better though, to write the WSDL and XSD's yourself and then generate axis stubs from it, that way you have full control over the xml format and it is also a best practice.

Comment: Yeah, I'm also considering going the other way (wsdl2java). However, since the Web services will be embedded on an existing Web app, I wanted for it to use the ?wsdl facility to generate the WSDLs. And an extra **Employees** class is quite "unnatural" (though I've seen Axis2 doing this). But yeah, this may be the simplest solution/work around. Thanks.